# Site keeps redirecting to HTTP when I visit HTTPS, for no apparent reason

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, joomla

I am trying to get SSL working for my site on a LAMP server.  When I type any page address on the site as https://www.example.com it gets redirected to http://www.example.com.

I think the SSL would work (or at least I could get it to) if I could get the server to go through HTTPS but it just refuses, and always changes to HTTP.  The site utilises Joomla! but I am pretty sure it's not relevant, as:

- I have another almost identical Joomla! site on the same server, and SSL works successfully.
- SSL certificate has been checked and is valid and installed correctly.
- There are no PHP redirects.
- There are no .htaccess redirects directly pertaining to HTTP/S, etc.

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteRule ^order/payment(/?.*)$ /payment [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^order/complete$ /index.php?option=com_cake&task=orders&id=complete [L]
RewriteRule ^order2$ /index.php?option=com_cake&task=orders&id=index [L]
RewriteRule ^order/2$ /index.php?option=com_cake&task=orders&id=index [L]
RewriteRule ^payment/(.+)$ /index.php?option=com_cake&task=payments&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ /index.php?option=com_cake&task=admin&id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

So why is the site redirecting?  Any ideas?

For anyone who knows Joomla! I tried installing this plugin http://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/ssl-redirect and tried enabling the 'Secure' option on my home page and it doesn't work.  I assume this is because it probably is working but the server is redirecting to HTTP again, for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to rule out any Joomla configuration issues is to upload an empty file in to the root directory. Call it ssltest.html, then access that file using https. If it still redirects then you have a server/certificate installation issue and your host needs to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
   RewriteEngine on
   Options +FollowSymLinks 
   # Rewrite to https
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Have already tried.  It causes an infinite redirect loop because I assume something else is causing HTTPS to redirect back to HTTP each time.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the Joomla Force SSL option in global configuration set and it's not working would you please report it as a bug?

Comment: This isn't an answer, you should use comments to make comments.

Comment: Yeah I should have just said "you know Joomla has an option for that, you should enable it."