# HTTPS redirects to HTTP

Tags: php, ssl, https

There was a thread as follows here regarding HTTPS redirects to HTTP:
[Site keeps redirecting to HTTP when I visit HTTPS, for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388272/site-keeps-redirecting-to-http-when-i-visit-https-for-no-apparent-reason)

I just began experiencing the same issues on a few sites I designed and nothing was changed to cause this redirect.  Now the store fronts are not able to work securely.

I'm at a loss here and have tried everything from forcing SSL only to get further error messages as follows: "the page isn't redirecting properly, firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.  This problem can sometimes be cause by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

I did upload a test.html file and was able to call it using https, so this is not a certificate issue.

Could this be an Apache issue?  Anyone have the same problem and solution?

Comment: Yes, SSL-errors are usually an Apache configuration error. Could you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior in Apache 2.4 with PHP.   Interestingly, when I hit a simple hello world php file in https://myserver.com/foo.php  I do not have this redirect problem.  I do see this problem in my mediawiki installation, though

Answer (score 2):

If you enable SSL then you can redirect any url from http to https in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if https on then turn off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# if https off then turn on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

keep in mind that this will redirect every page that is https. I'm not sure which you want so just comment the incorrect one out :)

- DO NOT paste both sets of code in there, or you will shut your site down